# Image Classification: Different Background on Training and Test Set

Tags: keras, tensorflow, image-classification

I am currently working on a challenge for a course at my university. We need to assign the image of a leaf to one of 14 different classes and we are given an unbalanced training set of ~17k pictures (the most popolous class has 5k samples, the least popolous has 500). What bothers me is that ALL the pictures of the training set we are given are characterized by a black background (i.e., the background has been removed), whereas I suspect that in the (hidden) test set they use to evaluate our work the images are of lower quality (i.e., the background has not been removed). Therefore whatever classifier I build performs worse on the data at my disposal (even if I don't use them for training but as a validation set only) than on the hidden data. Is there some kind of augmentation technique I can apply to my training set to have more robust performance regarding the background problem?
Thanks a lot.